# How to Load, render and display 3d model of obj format created by maya or blender in iphone with textures as png or jpg?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hi i know many wavefrontobj parsers are available in web to load .obj model but mostly are loading without textures so i need to know that how can we load TEXTURES(.png and .jpg). Also i have written code for scaling 3d model and for having interaction with it but its not working. So can anyone help me out there to cope with this problem. Any sample application having all above capabilities will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Code for Scaling:

```
- (void)scale:(id)sender 
{
    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
        lastScale = 1.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat prevZoomValue = zoomValue;
    CGFloat scale = (1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]))/10;

    if ([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale] < 1)
    {
        //user is zooming in
        // range 1.0 to 0.0
        zoomValue -= scale;
    }
    else 
    {
        //user is zooming out
        // range > 1.0
        zoomValue += scale/10;
    }

    // if zoom value is not in the range then restore last value
    if (!(zoomValue < -0.1 && zoomValue > -10.0))
    {
        zoomValue = prevZoomValue;
        lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
    }
}
```

Code for Interaction:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
//    NSMutableSet *currentTouches = [[[event touchesForView:self] mutableCopy] autorelease];
//    [currentTouches minusSet:touches];

    secondsInterval = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    //longPressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(startLongPressCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // New touches are not yet included in the current touches for the view
    lastMovementPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    rotateX = endMovementPosition.x;
    rotateY = endMovementPosition.y;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    idleRotate = FALSE;

    CGPoint currentMovementPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");

    rotateX = (lastMovementPosition.x - currentMovementPosition.x);
    rotateY = (lastMovementPosition.y - currentMovementPosition.y);

    //[self renderByRotatingAroundX:(lastMovementPosition.x - currentMovementPosition.x) rotatingAroundY:(lastMovementPosition.y - currentMovementPosition.y)];
    lastMovementPosition = currentMovementPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cubeimage" ofType:@"jpg"];
OpenGLTexture3D *newTexture = [[OpenGLTexture3D alloc] initWithFilename:path width:512 height:512];
self.texture = newTexture;
[newTexture release];
```